# Python: What is 'theweek' parameter in the formatweek() method in HTMLCalendar?

Tags: python, django, calendar

I am making a web app in Python/Django and I am trying to make a calendar that displays meetings using the HTMLCalendar class in the calendar module. 
I am overriding the `formatday()`, `formatweek()` and `formatmonth()` methods in HTMLCalendar.

I have written my new code for the `formatday()` function. I have found two code samples for the `formatweek()` function demonstrating its usage:

```
# Sample 1
def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d, events)
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

# Sample 2
def formatweek(self, theweek, width):
        """
        Returns a single week in a string (no newline).
        """
        return ' '.join(self.formatday(d, wd, width) for (d, wd) in theweek)
```

I am not sure what `theweek` parameter is exactly. I have searched online for documentation for `formatweek()` but I could not find anything that outlined what `theweek` parameter is. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code of [`calendar`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/132243957ce834cf5ffced4bf8e39d00f6e34e5f/Lib/calendar.py#L446) module, it seems like `formatweek` is expecting an array of `(day number, weekday number)` tuples as the value for `theweek` argument.

You can use [`monthdatescalendar`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/132243957ce834cf5ffced4bf8e39d00f6e34e5f/Lib/calendar.py#L237) API for this. As per the function docs string,

> This will Return a matrix representing a month's calendar.Each row
>   represents a week; week entries are (day number, weekday number)
>   tuples. Day numbers outside this month are zero.

```
>>> from calendar import TextCalendar
>>> cal = TextCalendar()
>>> for week in cal.monthdays2calendar(2019, 11):
...     print(cal.formatweek(week, 10))
...
                                                 1          2          3
     4          5          6          7          8          9         10
    11         12         13         14         15         16         17
    18         19         20         21         22         23         24
    25         26         27         28         29         30
```